# JQuery fadeToggle strange side effect when on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

fadeToggle works OK on static HTML elements:
HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 116px;
height: 116px;
background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Example.jpg/116px-Example.jpg') no-repeat;
">
<img id="cover" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Example.png/116px-Example.png" />
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#wrapper").click(function() {
    $("#cover").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BishKopt/zFq5P/1/

But when I try to add the wrapper with JQuery...

HTML:

```
<img id="cover" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Example.png/116px-Example.png" />
```

JQUERY:

```
$wrapper = $('<div></div>');
$wrapper.attr('id', 'mywrapper');
$wrapper.css({
    position: "relative",
    display: "inline-block",
    width: $("#cover").width(),
    height: $("#cover").height(),
    background: "url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Example.jpg/116px-Example.jpg') no-repeat"
});
$("#cover").wrap($wrapper);

$("#mywrapper").click(function() {
    $("#cover").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BishKopt/kazKF/1/

...after the second toggle (second click) - the img html element gets "selected"...
Do you have any ideas how to avoid it? Thanks!

Comment: both the jsfiddle is behaving same only,please explain what you meant by "selected"

Answer (score 1):

If by "selected" you mean text selection, then do this:

CSS:

```
#mywrapper{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

However, if you mean your browser is adding an unwanted border around the div, then do this:

CSS:

```
#mywrapper{
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've already managed to "hack it"... But I guess your method is a better method though...

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve it with a kind of "hack"...

```
$("#cover").after($('<a style="display: hidden; position: absolute;" id="hack"></a>'));

$("#mywrapper").click(function() {
    $("#cover").fadeToggle("slow");
    $("#hack").blur();
});
```